# Expression: String Subscript Out of Range

Tags: c++

I am getting an error saying that my string subscript is out of range (the error message is the title) whenever I run my code. I expect it to be from using "counter" to calculate total cities and average population. How do I go about fixing this? I have tried other methods to calculate it but none have worked.

```
void cities( istream& in, ostream& out )
{
    ifstream ("cities.txt");
    string country, city, city2, state, lat, longi;
    int pop;
    int currentPop = 0;
    int smallestPop = 0;
    int largestPop = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int average = 0;
    string largestCity;
    string smallestCity;
    string population;

    readLineOfData(in, country, city, city2, state, pop, lat, longi);
    while(!in.fail())
    {
        counter++;
        output( out, country, city, city2, state, pop, lat, longi );


        readLineOfData(in, country, city, city2, state, pop, lat, longi);

        population[counter] = pop;

        if (pop < smallestPop || smallestPop == 0)
        {
            smallestPop = pop;
            smallestCity = city2;
        }

        if (pop > largestPop || largestPop == 0)
        {
            largestPop = pop;
            largestCity = city2;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i<counter; i++)
        {
            sum += population[i];
            average = sum/counter;
        }
    }

        out << "Smallest City: " << smallestCity << endl;
        out << "Population: " << smallestPop << endl;
        out << endl;
        out << "Largest City: " << largestCity << endl;
        out << "Largest Population: " << largestPop << endl;
        out << endl;
        out << "Total Cities: " << i << endl;
        out << "Average Population: " << average << endl;
    return;
}

void readLineOfData( istream& in, string &country,  string &city, string &city2, 
    string &state, int &pop, string &lat, string &longi)
{
    getline( in, country, ',');
    getline( in, city, ',');
    getline( in, city2, ',');
    getline( in, state, ',');
    in >> pop;
    in.ignore( 200, ',' );
    getline( in, lat, ',');
    getline( in, longi, '\n' );

}

void output( ostream& out, string country, string city, string city2,
    string state, int pop, string lat, string longi )
{
}
```

Comment: error message that you are getting?

Comment: the one from the title

Comment: is population is single string or array of strings

Comment: Where in the code are you getting this error?

Comment: on what line? Give proper information please

Comment: If population is integer then use an integer array

Comment: i get the error when i run the code

Comment: pop is an integer, population is an array with each pop. i used string because i have to define how many integers will be in the array while i will have an unknown ammount.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration

```
string population;
```

means that `population` is a sequence of character codes, but you're treating it as a sequence of numbers:

```
population[counter] = pop;
```

also at this point its size is 0, so indexing will just err out or give undefined behavior.

instead, declare `population` as a `std::vector`, and use

```
population.push_back( pop );
```